# Implement Database(MySQL) in a Restlet application

Tags: java, mysql, rest, restlet

I'm building a restlet webservice with lots of connections(1000 users) from the clients to a MySQL database.

1. Should I use a framework like Hibernate to handle data(I figure I could hack out what i need using JDBC)?
2. What are the memory issues i should be considering(what exactly should i be able to do in memory and what should't i do)?
3. Any good tutorial on using Restlets and MySQL?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my 2 cents of advice

1) Hiberate+ehcache to avoid hitting the database too often would be the way to go

2) Use ehcache and configure it properly depending on your application needs, it is a very flexible framework

3) I never used restlet but I used RESTEasy from jboss that was very well documented and well suited for my rest needs.

Comment: thanks Philippe.. after researching, I settled on hibernate.. don't know ehcache.. checking it out.

Comment: ehcache is a caching framework, will allow you to avoid hitting database every time you need data.